# grep -r (or -R) does not search inside subfolders

Tags: command-line, grep, findstr

It has been some time since I don't use linux, using windows instead. 
In windows whenever I want to search for a string on files and files inside subfolders I do (for example for cs files)

`findstr /s /i /n "Thepattern" *.cs`

lately, I found out that you can use grep in MINGW64 that is installed when using Git. So I tried

`grep --color -n -r "Thepattern" *.cs`

But even though I put `-r` the search does not include the subdirectories.

What am I doing wrong with grep? and how it should be?

EDIT:
Anaksunaman provided me with the correct answer:

`grep --color -n -r --include=*.cs "Thepattern"`

and several other options :)
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to remove `*.cs`.

Comment: but I want to search only on cs files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found out that you can use grep in MINGW64 that is installed when using Git.

I am assuming you are referring to Git Bash.

> What am I doing wrong with grep? And how it should be?

You should try this:

```
 grep --color -n -r --include=*.cs "ThePattern"
```

`--include=` should come after `-r`. This will limit results to files that end with ".cs". You can also specify a directory if you wish e.g.:

```
grep --color -n -r --include=*.cs "ThePattern" ~/some/directory/'with spaces'
```

In this case, `~` refers to your user profile folder on Windows.

Also, assuming "ThePattern" is a string literal, you may need to include `-i` to make things case insensitive e.g.:

```
 grep --color -n -i -r --include=*.cs "ThePattern"
```

Otherwise, "ThePattern" is not the same as e.g. "Thepattern" and you may not get any results.

*Note that you can always use `grep --help` to get information on additional options.*

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gave the intended result. (I checked grep documentation indeed but obviously was not clear enough for me)

Comment: Glad you got things working. Documentation isn't always the clearest, no. =)